# Display two columns data in textarea using table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I am trying to display the data from two columns in a database table inside a textarea in php, under the headings tag number and scc

It should read something like this.

[image]

However it reads all in one line with no breaks and it looks messy:

[image]

Here is my code, I would appreciate some advice on how to structure this in a table format or something neat. The lines in ***bold*** are were I have displayed the two columns data in the textarea. $MyText1 & $Out1 displays the data in the textarea.

```
 // mysqli_fetch_assoc
    $myquery = "SELECT  `scc`, `tag_number` FROM  `milk` 
";

         $result = mysql_query($myquery);

$MyText = "";
$MyText1 = "";

    //$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {

  $Scc = $row['scc'];
    $TagNumber= $row['tag_number']; 
    //$MyText.= $row['tag_number']; 
    $MyText .= $TagNumber . ', ';
    ***$MyText1 .= $TagNumber . $Scc . ',';***

   ***$msg1 = "TagNumber :   Scc : " .$row[0].$row[1];*** 
  // $out1 = '<p align="left"><textarea rows="5" cols="25" disabled = "true">' .$msg1. '</textarea></p>';
    //mysqli_fetch_array($result) 
//  echo $out1;



     if($row['scc'] > 50 ) {
        $msg = ("'Somanic cell count levels are meeting the expected output levels in the herd.' $MyText. 'are above the average' 'No further action should be taken according to current production levels '");
    //$msg = $TagNumber;

//echo $row.$TagNumber;
}
    elseif ($Scc < $average) {
        $msg = 'SCC levels are below the average.';
    }else{
        $msg = 'some other message';
    }
  }
    ***$out1 = '<p align="left"><textarea rows="5" cols="25" disabled = "true">'.$msg1.$MyText1.  '</textarea></p>';***
    //mysqli_fetch_array($result) 
    ***echo $out1;***
```

Comment: Don't use a hammer to grout tiles. Why are you using a textarea for tabular data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the textarea tag you can use the tab character to simulate the columns and the \n to generate new lines. Textarea does not accept a table tag inside it. You can get the data from your database and then separate it using the \n and \t tags. Your code should be something like this:

```
echo "Column1Title: \t Column2Title \n";
...
echo "Column1Data1 \t Column2Data2 \n";
...
```

The blank spaces closer to the \t and \n are no mandatory. But rember: the \n and \t characeters should always be echoed with " and not with '.

**UPDATE**

Base on your code, you can try something like this:

```
$myText = "TagNumber: \t\t Scc:\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $myText .= $row['tag_number']."\t\t".$row['scc']."\n";
      (...)
}
```